# Allegro CL: creating a standalone binary?

Tags: build, lisp, common-lisp, allegro-cl

I want to save a third-party lisp library to a standalone binary? Is this possible to do in Allegro CL (I can't seem to find anything about this in the documentation)?

Comment: Generally EVERY Lisp can generate standalone binaries, somehow.
Allegro CL has support mailing lists - application specific questions are best asked there.
The documentation has detailed instructions, too.
http://franz.com/support/documentation/9.0/doc/delivery.htm
http://franz.com/support/documentation/9.0/doc/contents.htm#dumplisp
http://franz.com/support/documentation/9.0/doc/building-images.htm

Comment: right.. apparently I wasn't looking in the right places (I've never used Allegro before). Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Allegro has some documentation on the subject [here](http://franz.com/support/documentation/8.1/doc/delivery.htm#delivery-intro-1) and [here](http://franz.com/support/documentation/8.1/doc/building-images.htm) depending on what you are trying to do.

You might also want to check out [CLiki's page](http://www.cliki.net/creating%20executables) on the subject if you want to use any other implementations.